# Julia dot vectorization - how deep into call chain do I need to vectorize?

Tags: julia, vectorization

I'm trying to grok Julia's dot vectorization syntax with a very simple example of a linear interpolating spline.

```
function createlookup(xk)
    min_i = 1
    max_i = size(xk, 1) - 1
    function inner(x)
        max(min(searchsorted(xk, x).stop, max_i), min_i)
    end
    inner
end


function linear_dydx(x, y)
    diff(y, dims=1) ./ diff(x, dims=1)
end


function linear(xₖ, yₖ)
    segment = createlookup(xₖ)
    dydxₖ = linear_dydx(xₖ, yₖ)
    function inner(x)
        i = segment(x)
        y = yₖ[i] + dydxₖ[i] * (x - xₖ[i])
    end
    inner
end


function main()
    xₖ = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
    yₖ = [0.0, 2.0, 10.0, 13.0]
    interpolator = linear(xₖ, yₖ)

    x = [i/2.0 for i=0:10]

    println(interpolator(2.43))
    println(interpolator.(x))
end

main()
```

How deep in the call chain do I need to use the dot notation to make sure my `main()` call to `interpolator.(x)` is fully vectorized by the interpreter?

- Does `createlookup` need any vectorization?
- Is `linear_dydx` already vectorized via `diff` and `./`?
- Do I need `@.` in front of `y = yₖ[i] + dydxₖ[i] * (x - xₖ[i])`?

I find myself throwing dots everywhere and nowhere and am not quite sure how to check whether I'm capturing everything while still preserving the broadcasting flexibility that dot notation is supposed to preserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general strategy to keep in mind is to write all your functions as scalar functions if that makes sense. Once you've written your scalar operations, you can then apply them to the array by using `.` once.

Comment: This seems to have worked, at least functionally. Is there a profiling tool I can use to make sure the single vectorization happened as intended?

Comment: What do you mean "happened as intended"?

Comment: Was optimized (e.g. minimized temp arrays, etc.)

Comment: `@profile` or `@profview` from `ProfileView` might help. That said, if you are only broadcasting once, you will only get 1 array allocation (0 if you preallocate output)

Comment: You can also use BenchmarkTools.jl (which you should basically use for all your benchmarks anyway). It will tell you the number and size of allocations. If it says "1 allocation" you're definitely good. Very easy to use, too.